# How to alllow template class constructor to support different number of arguments depending on base type?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor

I have code similar to the following:

```
class CIntColumn : public CColumn
{
public:
    CIntColumn(LPCTSTR pszName)
    {
    }
    // Etc.
}

class CTextColumn : public CColumn
{
public:
    CTextColumn(LPCTSTR pszName, int nMaxLength)
    {
    }
    // Etc.
}

template<typename BASE_TYPE>
CNullableColumn : public BASE_TYPE
{
public:
    // Questions about code that goes here
}

class CNullableIntColumn : public CNullableColumn<CIntColumn>
{
public:
    CNullableIntColumn(LPCTSTR pszName)
        : CNullableColumn<CIntColumn>(pszName)
    {
    }
}

class CNullableTextColumn : public CNullableColumn<CTextColumn>
{
public:
    CNullableTextColumn(LPCTSTR pszName, int nMaxLength)
        : CNullableColumn<CTextColumn>(pszName, nMaxLength)
    {
    }
}
```

As is, this code won't compile because `CNullableIntColumn` needs to pass a single argument to the base class, and `CNullableTextColumn` needs to pass two arguments to the base class.

Is there any trick to modify my `CNullableColumn<>` template class so it supports both cases? Ideally, I could use some sort of conditional compilation but C++ doesn't seem to support they kind that would be needed here.

Comment: Do you want `CNullableColumn` to pass some constant to `int nMaxLength`, or do you want an extra constructor parameter for it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I want it to pass the constructor parameters down to `CTextColumn`. Sorry, updated the code.

Comment: Maybe you could inherit the constructors instead of writing them by hand? (`using BASE_TYPE::BASE_TYPE` in `CNullableColumn`, `using CNullableColumn<blah>::CNullableColumn` in the derived classses) This would only work if in your actual code `CNullable*Column` constructors don't do anything except for calling parents' constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what Xirema *seemed* to be originally suggesting, the following appears to work.

```
template <typename BASE_TYPE>
class CNullableColumn : public BASE_TYPE
{
protected:
    template<typename T1>
    CNullableColumn<BASE_TYPE>(T1 pszName)
        : BASE_TYPE(pszName)
    {
    }

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    CNullableColumn<BASE_TYPE>(T1 pszName, T2 nMaxLength)
        : BASE_TYPE(pszName, nMaxLength)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a generic forwarding constructor that will take any number of arguments and pass them to the base class for `CNullableColumn`:

```
template<typename BASE_TYPE>
class CNullableColumn : public BASE_TYPE {
public:
    template<typename ... Args>
    CNullableColumn(Args && ... args) :
        BASE_TYPE(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

This should cause all your later uses of `CNullableTextColumn` and `CNullableIntColumn` to forward their arguments correctly to their roots.

---

So if you know in advance that each type will only ever have exactly 1 argument, except for one or two specific types that will have two, you might prefer template specialization instead:

```
template<typename BASE_TYPE>
class CNullableColumn : public BASE_TYPE {
public:
    CNullableColumn(LPCTSTR pszName) :
        BASE_TYPE(pszName) {}
};

//Specialization
template<>
class CNullableColumn<CTextColumn> : public CTextColumn {
public:
    CNullableColumn(LPCTSTR pszName, int maxLength) :
        CTextColumn(pszName, maxLength) {}
};

//Could create other specializations for other types with different #s of arguments, if needed
```

Now, the disadvantage of Template Specialization is that you have to be clever in your implementation to avoid duplicating code. But it'll at least elegantly solve the problem you're trying to deal with without just turning everything into a Varargs nightmare.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But I have a number of different type of `CNullableColumn`s. Only `CNullableTextColumn` has two arguments. Do I still need a constructor for every type that derives from `CNullableColumn`?

Comment: Actually, if I understand correctly, I only need to create one for each parameter type and count. Let me see if I can figure out the syntax.

Comment: @JonathanWood Every class you define does need to specify its own constructor. You might be able to get away with using the same "perfect vararg forwarding" for those other classes, but it might result in some extremely ugly error messages if you later write code that doesn't properly respect the intended API. Heck, you could probably just ditch `CNullableXColumn` and just do `CNullableColumn<X>` for all the references you need.

Comment: I don't think I can do your last suggestion as each version can have specialized code. If all my derived classes pass only one argument, then it appears I only need one constructor in my template class. (Yes, each derived class has their own constructor.) And I still haven't quite grokked the syntax needed for two versions. What is `Args`?

Comment: @JonathanWood Hmm. Maybe a better candidate is Template Specialization. That's a bit orthogonal to your original question, but I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @JonathanWood Alright, does the section about Template Specialization help?

Comment: Doesn't `CNullableColumn<CTextColumn>` bypass my `CNullableClass` completely? Wouldn't this ignore the methods in my `CNullableClass`? I'm still curious what `Args` would be in your first answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can specialize a class *and* inherit from a different class. I'm not sure what the effect of that is. Also, that syntax gives me an error: `E0834 invalid partial specialization -- class "CNullableColumn<<error-type>>" is already fully specialized`

Comment: @JonathanWood [This is the original version substituted into your code](https://godbolt.org/z/ORXt7W), along with a few fixes for the syntax. It compiles just fine; whether or not it's a suitable solution for your needs is something you'll have to judge for yourself. I replaced the references to `LPCTSTR` because I didn't want to pull in the windows headers, but I *believe* `char const*` is the usual replacement for that.